# IsNull not returning 0 on SQL query

Tags: sql, count, isnull

I have tried IsNull, Case statements and searched online, but for some reason if no records are found it still doesn't show a record or replace it with a '0' I'm trying to get all of the Types from the table and display how many have been done within a date range.

Here is my code so far.

```
SELECT     ISNULL(COUNT(Type), 0) AS Total, Type
FROM         dbo.Refs
WHERE     (DateSubmitted BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY Type
```

The Type column is a varchar to unfortunaltey

Thanks

Comment: If no records are found then there's nothing for the ISNULL, CASE, etc to be applied to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table that stores your types you can use:

```
SELECT  COUNT(r.Type) AS Total, t.Type
FROM    TypeTable t
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Refs r
            ON r.Type = t.Type 
            AND r.DateSubmitted >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND r.DateSubmitted <=  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
GROUP BY t.Type;
```

Otherwise you will need to use your existing table to get a list of all types, before joining to the table filtered by date:

```
SELECT  COUNT(r.Type) AS Total, t.Type
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM dbo.Refs) t
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Refs r
            ON r.Type = t.Type 
            AND r.DateSubmitted >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102) 
            AND r.DateSubmitted <=  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102)
GROUP BY t.Type;
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN r.DateSubmitted >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-02-01 00:00:00', 102) 
                        AND r.DateSubmitted <=  CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 102) 
                    THEN 1
                END) AS Total, 
        t.Type
FROM    dbo.Refs r
GROUP BY r.Type;
```

The best method will depend on your indexes/if you do or don't have a table to store all types.

Comment: +1 for including the WHERE-part in the join-condition

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm afraid there isn't a look up table, so its down to options 2 and 3 you have given. Although when I try to run the second piece of SQL I am getting the following error?

Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Comment: I missed out the `FROM` in the subquery!! Shocking! I have corrected it now, so it should run now.

Comment: Thank you, made my Friday that little better! Working great.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use a group by to achieve what you want -See the following post 
[Count Returning blank instead of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221630/count-returning-blank-instead-of-0)