# When count is giving blank with group by how to replace it with 0 in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

below is the code which i am trying but its is giving blank . I need to insert this result as a row in another table, as it is giving blank due to which i am not able insert it into another table . Can someone please suggest how to replace that count result ''  with 0

```
Select case when (count(ID) is Null ) OR   (count( ID) =''  )
    
    then  0 else cast((count( ID)) as varchar(50)) end as Total 

     from Temp1 
          where 
            quarter  in ('202203','202204') 
           group by  ID , Quarter    having count(ID) >1
```

Comment: Your query cannot give a null count... there is no need to "replace" anything.

Comment: `COUNT()` will never return `NULL`

Comment: its giving blank

Comment: @Squirrel group by forces an empty set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count Returning blank instead of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221630/count-returning-blank-instead-of-0)

Comment: `its giving blank` because you have a `CASE` expression that convert it to string

Comment: empty result set does not means `COUNT()` return a `NULL` value

Comment: *"group by forces an empty set"* `GROUP BY` can't do this either.

Comment: @Larnu please run `select  count(1)  from sys.tables where 1<>1 group by type `

Comment: The `GROUP BY` has nothing to do with filtering the data, @DhruvJoshi , that's the `WHERE`... There is **never** an event where `1` isn't equal to `1`...

Comment: @larnu have a look at the screenshot in my answer. create a table, delete all rows, run the  count(1) with group by (w/o where). same result

Comment: @Larnu `create table temptable (id int)
insert into temptable values (1),(2);
delete from temptable
select count(1) from temptable group by id `

Comment: That's still not filtering, @DhruvJoshi ... The `WHERE` returns no row, but because you have another column, which has no rows, no rows are returned. The `GROUP BY` isn't forcing the empty result set, the `WHERE` is. If you removed the `GROUP BY` (and `COUNT`) you would *still* get an empty result set.

Comment: @Larnu still suggest you to have a look at the screenshot in answer or run `create table t (i int);
select count(1) from t;
select count(1) from t group by i` on your sql server

Comment: @Larnu Sure "group by forces an empty set" is true, eg: `GROUP BY ()` returns an empty set, see https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this does not do anything you look at the group by part first.
Group by eliminates all rows and then there is no count in the group by.

to counter this condition use not exists like below

```
if not exists (Select  cast((count( ID)) as varchar(50)) as Total 

     from Temp1 
          where 
            quarter  in ('202203','202204') 
           group by  ID , Quarter    having count(ID) >1  )  
begin
insert into #result(total) select 0 as total
end
else
begin
insert into #result(total)
Select  cast((count( ID)) as varchar(50)) as Total 

     from Temp1 
          where 
            quarter  in ('202203','202204') 
           group by  ID , Quarter    having count(ID) >1
end
```

See demo below where I created an empty table

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link: [Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221630/count-returning-blank-instead-of-0)

You need to add union and sum of your Id.

Check the following way.

```
    select sum(Total) as Total from (
    Select case when (count(ID) is Null ) OR   (count( ID) =''  )
    
    then  0 else cast((count( ID)) as varchar(50)) end as Total 

     from Temp1 
          where 
            quarter  in ('202203','202204') 
           group by  ID , Quarter    having count(ID) >1 
           union all
           select 0 as Total
           ) report
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
Select case when (ISNULL(count(ID),0)=0)
       then 0 else cast((count( ID)) as varchar(50))
       end as Total 
from Temp1 
where quarter in ('202203','202204') 
group by ID, Quarter
having count(ID) >1
```